# Accessing variable value from inside method of php class

Tags: php, class, object, variables

```
class ABC{
    public function __construct(){}
    // There have a parameter
    public function check($data){
    // There have a variable
        $available = null;
        if(true){
          $available = true;
        }else{
          $available = false;
        }
    }
}


$obj= new ABC();

// I want to access this $available

$obj->available;
```

How can I access `$available` value from the class method? 
 Is there a dynamic parameter in this method (this is the problem)?

Comment: you cant access a variable from a class method. you can set a public property $available and then access it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently `$available` is only visible in the scope of your `check` function. You need to create a local variable for `$available` and set its visibility to `public` then you can change that variable in the `ABC` class and access it from outside of the class.

```
<?php 
    class ABC {
        public $available = true;

        public function __construct(){}
        public function check($data){
            // There have a variable

            if($data){
                $available = true;
            }else{
              $available = false;
            }
        }

        // create an optional getter for the variable 
        public function isAvailable() {
            return $available;
        }
    }

$obj= new ABC();

// I want to access this $available
echo $obj->available

// or access it through the getter
echo $obj->isAvailable()
```